# How to skip the content_for tag content for some pages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, content-for

I have a layout in which i'm using the content_for tag to render some partials(for sidebar). But on several pages I don't need this sidebar. So the question is: How can I tell rails not to render anything for some pages?

I've tried to do it the following way without any result:

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <%= render nothing: true %>
<% end %>
```

Just got an error

```
You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template, :inline, :file or :text option.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't specify content_for in views you don't want to see the contents

Comment: That is. Specified new layout for the pages where side bar should be eliminated.

Comment: Also -- if you need to know if content was specified, you can run `<% if content_for?(:sidebar) %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= render text: "&nbsp;" %>
```

Comment: The problem is that :sidebar already has some content. So this code just appends new text.